# Parse an HTML log file and get a text file in a specific format

Tags: perl

I want to parse a text file using Perl. This text file contains log of some HTML files as shown below:

```
Details from /projects/git/Changelog.html file:
NEW_FEATURES: <a href="http://jira.xyz.com/browse/JIRA-4208">JIRA-4208</a><span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>   </span>Add New Config C support in code
BUG_FIX: <a href="http://jira.xyz.com/browse/BUGJIRA-31">BUGJIRA-31</a><span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>   </span>Bugfix of some old bug
NEW_FEATURES: <a href="http://jira.xyz.com/browse/ZEERA-273">ZEERA-273</a><span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>   </span>Add support for some other feature.

Details from /projects/git/Changelog2.html file:
BUG_FIX: <a href="http://jira.xyz.com/browse/BUGJIRA-33">BUGJIRA-33</a><span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>   </span>Bugfix of an issue
NEW_FEATURES: <a href="http://jira.xyz.com/browse/JIRA-4209">JIRA-4209</a><span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>   </span>Add New Config D support in code
```

Each line contains a Bug Number and its Description.

After parsing, the EXPECTED OUTPUT is as under:

```
JIRA-4208, BUGJIRA-31, ZEERA-273, BUGJIRA-33, JIRA-4209 : Add New Config C support in code, Bugfix of some old bug, Add support for some other feature, Bugfix of an issue, Add New Config D support in code
```

i.e. all bug numbers followed by their descriptions.

If possible i would like to write the output in another file `output.txt`

EDIT-1:

My code is as under:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open (FILE, 'input_file1.txt') or die "Could not read from file, exit...";
while(<FILE>)
{
  chomp;
  ($junk0,$junk1,$junk2,$junk3,$junk4,$BUG_NUMBR) = split /[:<="">]+/,$_;
  print "$BUG_NUMBR \n";
}
close FILE;
exit;
```

And the output is:

```
JIRA-4208 
BUGJIRA-31 
ZEERA-273 
BUGJIRA-33 
JIRA-4209
```

This is quite different from the expected output as shown above. I'm not able to define the appropriate regex for the second part of expected output which is a short description of the bug.

Comment: So what exactly have you tried? whats not working in your code? whats the question here?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle: I have added my sample code and explained its limitations also. Kindly request you to suggest a solution.

Comment: Do you really want a list of all the bug numbers, followed by a list of all the descriptions?

Comment: yes, the EXPECTED_OUTPUT is the commit message with which i will finally commit the changes in repo. "git commit -m $EXPECTED_OUTPUT"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression for that. Your `split` pattern is interesting, but it gets the job done.

Just take the rest of the result as well. I've replaced your `$junk` variables with an array. Perl lets you take the last element from the right with the index `-1`, so it's trivial to get the text out, as it's after the last `>`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ( @numbers, @text );
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @stuff = split /[:<="">]+/, $line;
    push @numbers, $stuff[5];
    push @text, $stuff[-1];
}

print join ', ', @numbers;
print ' : ';
print join ', ', @text;

__DATA__
NEW_FEATURES: <a href="http://jira.xyz.com/browse/JIRA-4208">JIRA-4208</a><span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>   </span>Add New Config C support in code
BUG_FIX: <a href="http://jira.xyz.com/browse/BUGJIRA-31">BUGJIRA-31</a><span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>   </span>Bugfix of some old bug
NEW_FEATURES: <a href="http://jira.xyz.com/browse/ZEERA-273">ZEERA-273</a><span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>   </span>Add support for some other feature.
BUG_FIX: <a href="http://jira.xyz.com/browse/BUGJIRA-33">BUGJIRA-33</a><span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>   </span>Bugfix of an issue
NEW_FEATURES: <a href="http://jira.xyz.com/browse/JIRA-4209">JIRA-4209</a><span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>   </span>Add New Config D support in code
```

I also added strict and warnings, and made your variables lexical.

Also remember that your code will break if the text contains a literal `>` or `<` or quotes or whatever. It's a weird format you're having there, and a HTML parser is not really going to help you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. It works for me with some exceptions. The data set that you have used in your example is different from the data set that i gave in the problem statement above. With my data set there are some warnings and extra commas(,). Nevertheless, its a good starting point for me. I will share the final code when i fix the issues. Thanks again!!

Comment: Hi @simbabque, You mentioned that my `split` pattern is interesting although it gets the job done. I agree to this because I got it vial trial and error. Kindly request you to suggest a better way for `split` pattern.

Comment: @Yash I didn't realize that it was all one file. Sorry. You did the right thing to just check if the `^Details` are in the current line. By _interesting_ I meant that the approach is unconventional. I would have probably written a pattern to capture the exact things I want, but your approach works, too. Just keep in mind that it breaks if the input changes.

Comment: yes, i agree with you. Since i expect the input `textfile` to follow same pattern every time, the current `split` syntax works for me.

Comment: Hi @simbabque, one question, say if i want to print the JIRA number after the first occurrence of `^Details` only and don't want the JIRA numbers after subsequent occurrence of `^Details`. In this case, what changes shall be done ?

Comment: @Yash use a variable to keep track of if you have seen it already. Either a simple scalar for if you want it in general, or a hash if you want it per issue.

Comment: Thanks @simbabque, your approach worked.  The additional code is `use strict;

my $count = 0;
open (IN, "input.txt");
while (<IN>) {
    if (/START/) {
    $count = 1;
    }
    elsif (/END/) {
    $count = 0;
    }
    elsif ($count) {
    print;
    }
}
close IN;`

Answer (score 0):

The code for the problem statement mentioned above is as under:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open (FILE, 'perl_input_file1.txt') or die $!;
my ( @numbers, @text );
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    chomp $line;
    $line =~ /^Details/ and next;
    my @stuff = split /[:<="">]+/, $line;
    push @numbers, $stuff[5];
    push @text, $stuff[-1];
}
close FILE;
print join ', ', @numbers;
print ': ';
print join ', ', @text;
print "\n";
```

The output of this code is:

```
JIRA-4208, BUGJIRA-31, ZEERA-273, BUGJIRA-33, JIRA-4209: Add New Config C support in code, Bugfix of some old bug, Add support for some other feature, Bugfix of an issue, Add New Config D support in code
```

This is same as my desired expected output as mentioned in the question.

I would like to thank @simbabque once again for his guidance and approach.

Regards,